# Why does my Vuepress site work locally but not when hosted on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, vuepress

So I successfully deployed my basic/static vuepress site via `firebase deploy` but nothing is showing up when I go to the url; https://nbamodel-223111.web.app/. However, it works fine when running it locally. What could it be? Firebase seems to say the version it is running, multiple files etc... I don't know what's going on.

The `firebase.json` is the below - could there be something wrong there?

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "./vuepress/dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what else to look for to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you run `yarn docs:build` or `npm run docs:build` before uploading your code with `firebase deploy`?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your web at `https://********-223111.web.app/` and it shows that is up and running, you may want to edit your question to remove that url from Stackoverflow.

Additionally you could add how you made it work!!